# Long Argument Indentation in emacs

Tags: emacs, styles, indentation

I am currently using "bsd" style indentation in emacs. I also prefer to limit myself to 80 character lines.

There are situations where I am passing many arguments to a function and exceed the 80 characters. When this happen, I insert a newline. Currently, if I use the automated indentation for the continuation of my line, I get the following:

```
function __TimeBlock($inputDay, $inputStartHour, $inputStartMinute,
$inputEndHour,  $inputEndMinute)
```

however, what I want is:

```
function __TimeBlock($inputDay, $inputStartHour, $inputStartMinute,
                     $inputEndHour,  $inputEndMinute)
```

It should line up so that it is directly below the first character after the paren above.

Is there a way to edit the indentations so that I will automatically get that behavior when I have a newline within a set of parens "()"?

I would like this to apply across any whitespace-ignoring languages I code in within emacs.

Comment: Indentation is up to the major mode to implement however it chooses, so solutions may vary from mode to mode (although many modes do derive from some common base, so it's usually not too bad in practice). Anyway, which modes do you want to do this for (and of those, which are non-default modes? You should link to what you're using. The above looks like PHP, for example, and there's no default php-mode).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good start for you:

```el
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)

(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  "Customisations for C-mode and its derivatives."
  (c-set-style "bsd"))
```

n.b. All the PHP modes I've seen derive from c-mode.

Or if you prefer:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `c-default-style` <kbd>RET</kbd>

and specify `bsd` as appropriate.

FWIW, the most specific syntactic context element symbol (for `c-offsets-alist`) for this question appears to be:

```
arglist-cont-nonempty  -- Subsequent argument list lines when at
                          least one argument follows on the same
                          line as the arglist opening paren.
```

(but it doesn't look like you'll need to override its value.)